# MessageExtensionMethods.ToHttpRequestMessage fails with an exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I ma using ToHttpRequestMessage extension method in the link shown here [MessageExtensionMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageextensionmethods.tohttprequestmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {

          Message soapMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "urn:MyAction", "TestBody");
          soapMessage.Properties.Add("httpRequest", new HttpRequestMessageProperty());

          HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = soapMessage.ToHttpRequestMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Exception message : {"Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'string', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'. "}

Any idea what am i doing wrong? Or is there a bug in the .NET code itself

Comment: If you change `"TestBody"` to `123` it will throw the same serialization exception except it will say `Encountered 'Element' with name 'int'`. So I'm sure it's the "TestBody" argument. however I don't know what to put there because Stream is abstract and using a class derived from stream doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ConradFrix Yep my goal is to convert incoming WCF message to HttpRequestMessage and try to send a request using HttpClient and i was hoping to use this inbuilt extension method that .NET provides but it doesn't seem to work i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with any kind of message object.The problem that i am seeing is because those extension methods aren’t meant to be used with any type of message, but only instances of ByteStreamMessage. It is not well documented in the docs but mentioned in the docs of the sister class

[HttpRequestMessageExtensionMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageextensionmethods.tomessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Message instance can be read, written and copied just as a traditional ByteStreamMessage instance. The Message instance can also "read" to retrieve the original HttpRequestMessage instance by calling the ToHttpRequestMessage extension method